# Gerar Tabelas e inserir formulas com intervalo variável (VBA)

Tags: vba

Boa tarde a todos!

Estou tentando desenvolver um código para exportar relatórios de forma automatizada e otimizar meu tempo no trabalho, porém estou com dificuldade em algumas etapas.

Vou colocar passo a passo qual é a minha intenção, para exemplificar melhor.

O que eu quero fazer?

1. Exportar o relatório do banco de dados (ok)
2. Deletar algumas colunas (ok)
3. Inserir fórmula Cont.ses e excluir linhas repetidas
4. Selecionar intervalo e deixar apenas registros exclusivos
5. Gerar tabela dinâmica
6. Gerar gráfico dinâmico (ok)
7. Enviar resultado por email

Qual ponto está dando problema?

Na etapa 3 (Inserir fórmula Cont.ses e excluir linhas repetidas) o meu código apresenta o erro "Erro em tempo de execução 1004 o Objeto range global falhou".

Neste ponto, estou tentando inserir um código que seja capaz de varrer o meu arquivo e identificar qual a ultima linha das minhas duas primeiras colunas, adicionar a formula (cont.ses) à uma terceira coluna, aplicá-la para esta nova coluna inteira. Depois o meu código precisa selecionar o intervalo completo das três colunas e manter apenas os registros exclusivos.

Minha intenção é selecionar apenas os registros exclusivos para gerar um gráfico dinâmico (parte que estou conseguindo fazer).

Qual é o meu problema?

O problema é que preciso gerar um código que funcione para qualquer quantidade de linhas e intervalo que eu exporte (colunas não variam), pois como esse é um relatório de produção, ele sempre será variável. Consigo que o meu código identifique a ultima linha, mas não que depois selecione e aplique as formulas e gere a tabela pra qualquer intervalo que surja.

Alguma ajuda seria muito bem vinda, por favor.

Segue o código que estou tentando (ainda sem a tabela dinamica)

```
Sub Relatorio ()


    Dim Caminho As String
    Dim linha As Integer
    Dim pergunta As Integer
    Dim ult_lin As Long, ult_lin2 As Long
    Dim intervalo As Range


    pergunta = MsgBox("Deseja Exportar este Relatório?", vbYesNo)

    If pergunta = vbYes Then

        ' Abrir arquivo

        Caminho = ThisWorkbook.Path
        Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Usuários
        Convidados\Desktop\VBA\Testes\dadosbrutos")
        Sheets("Sheet").Select


        Sheets("Sheet").Activate

        'Excluir colunas Macro

        Columns("C:E").Delete


        ' Adicionar formula contagem

        ult_lin = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row    'encontrar ultima linha da coluna A
        ult_lin2 = Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row   'encontrar ultima linha da coluna B

        Range("C3").Value = "Contagem"
        Range("C4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A"),
        Cells(ult_lin, 1).Value, Range("B3:B"), Cells(ult_lin2, 2).Value) 'AQUI
        'APRESENTA O ERRO MENCIONADO
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Cells(ult_lin, 3) 'POSSÍVEL PONTO DE ERRO,
        'POIS NÃO CONSIGO USAR ult_lin COM OBJETO RANGE.

        ' deixar somente registros exclusivos

        For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

            If Cells <> "" Then

                AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True 'não sei qual
                range botar aqui no inicio para completar o comando a lado

            End If

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Você não fechou com `End If` o `If pergunta = vbYes Then`

Comment: O que seria um registro exclusivo? Um Filtro resolveria?

Answer (score 0):

- Não ficaram claras suas dúvidas, poderia disponibilizar alguns dados?
- Qual é o critério para 'CountIfs' ?

na correção abaixo adotei como critério ">10"

```
    Range("C4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A" & ult_lin), ">10")
    Range("C4").Value = Range("C4").Value + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("B3:B" & ult_lin2), ">10")
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você está precisando, mas espero que este código ajude:

```
Sub Relatorio ()

Dim Caminho As String
Dim linha As Integer
Dim pergunta As Integer
Dim ult_lin As Long, ult_lin2 As Long
Dim intervalo As Range

pergunta = MsgBox("Deseja Exportar este Relatório?", vbYesNo)

If pergunta = vbYes Then    ' Abrir arquivo

    Caminho = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\UsuáriosConvidados\Desktop\VBA\Testes\dadosbrutos")
    Sheets("Sheet").Activate

    Activesheet.Columns("C:E").Delete    'Excluir colunas Macro

    ' Adicionar formula contagem
    ult_lin = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row    'encontrar ultima linha da coluna A
    ult_lin2 = Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row   'encontrar ultima linha da coluna B

    Range("C3").Value = "Contagem"
    Range("C4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A" & ult_lin), Cells(ult_lin, 1).Value, Range("B3:B" & ult_lin2), Cells(ult_lin2, 2).Value) 'AQUI APRESENTA O ERRO MENCIONADO
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Cells(ult_lin, 3) 'POSSÍVEL PONTO DE ERRO, POIS NÃO CONSIGO USAR ult_lin COM OBJETO RANGE.

    ' deixar somente registros exclusivos
    'Verifique o argumento Action
    Activesheet.Range("A1:C" & ult_lin).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:E2"), Unique:=True    'Troque o CriteriaRange para o seu intervalo de critérios
End if
```

End Sub